# Javascript API Submit Mistakes

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I was working on Translate Api App ;

I have get error message as:

> " Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null " .

I still cannot understand why I do have this message. 
Could any of you help me with that mistake :( 
I have to get Submit from Form to Input type " submit " . 
Still could solve...

HTML Codes ;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Translator App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <!--jQuery CDN-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<section class="main">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Welcome to Translator</h1>
        <h2>Translate in English,Spanish,German,Turkish</h2>
    <div class="language">
    <div class="languageto">
    <select class="firstlanguages" name="languages" id="langs">
    <option value="eng">English</option>
    <option value="tr">Turkish</option>
    <option value="de">German</option>
    <option value="sp">Spanish</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="tolanguage">
        <select id="tolanguage" name="tolanguage">
    <option value="toeng">Turkish</option>
    <option value="totr">English</option>
    <option value="tode">German</option>
    <option value="tosp">Spanish</option>
    </select>
    </div>    
    </div>
    <form id="translate-from">
    <div class="translate">
    <textarea class="firstmsj" name="message" placeholder="Maximum 500 Character" id="message"></textarea>
    <textarea class="secondmsj"  name="message" disabled placeholder="Your Translate"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input class="translatebtn" type="submit" value="Translate">

    </form>
    </div>   
</section>  
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/translate.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

and here that I have get error message ;

```
eventListeners();

function eventListeners(){
    let form = document.getElementById("translate-form");
    form.addEventListener('submit', translateWord);  // THİS PART GIVES ME ERROR MESSAGE

    document.querySelector('.firstlanguages').onchange = function(){

    }

}
const translate = new Translate(document.getElementById("message").value,document.getElementById("langs").value)
function translateWord(e){



    e.preventDefault();
}
```

EXACT ERROR MESSAGE PARTS :

```
    function eventListeners(){
        let form = document.getElementById("translate-form");
        form.addEventListener('submit', translateWord);  // THİS PART GIVES ME ERROR MESSAGE

        document.querySelector('.firstlanguages').onchange = function(){

        }

    }
```

What shall I do?

Comment: translate-from vs translate-form

Comment: You have `translate-from` in your **HTML**. In your **JS** you are looking for `translate-form`.

Comment: premature closure as a duplicate considering it's a simple typo

Comment: I AM BLIND! 
Thank you guys for help! :)